# How can I find out which source files in my project are using a specific gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I would like to remove the `rd-readline` gem because it plays tricks with the Rails console. However, I don't know if the project's source code uses it somewhere. How do I determine if it is safe to remove the gem from `Gemfile`?

Comment: There may be some heuristic ways, but no way that will work for sure. For example, even doing grep over all methods and constants defined in the gem has a slight chance of missing method calls via (non-trivial) string composition followed by a `send` call.

Comment: I doubt `rd-readline` is used in `group :production`, so I would go with _remove-and-see-who-screams_ approach.

Comment: _"How do I determine if it is safe to remove ..."_ – by running your tests.